# Variables are not passing from one test set to another?

Tags: python, rest, pyresttest

I declared variables in config and I am using them in the test case below. The variables are not passing. I am not able to figure out the actual issue.

```
- config:
      - variable_binds: {'user_id': 'ravitej', 'pass': 'password', 'auth': 'plain'}
- test:
    - name:"login success"
    - url: "/api/login"
    - method: "POST"
    - body: '{"username": "$user_id", "password": "$pass", "authtype": "$auth"}'
    - headers: {Content-Type: application/json}
    - expected_status: [200]
    - group: "User"
```

In this below case: I'm running the first test set and I'm getting some auth_token in response this auth_token is saved to auth_key to use in another test set, but this auth_key is not passing to the 2nd test set. It was passing an empty variable. I tried all possible ways which are posted in GitHub still I am getting the same problem

```
- test:
      - name: "Registration"
      - url: "/api/register"
      - method: "POST"
      - body: '{"device_id": "0080", "device_key": "imAck", "device_name": "teja", "device_description": "Added By Ravi", "project_tag": "MYSTQ-16", "attributes": "{}"}'
      - headers: {Content-Type: application/json}
      - expected_status: [200]
      - group: "Register"
      - extract_binds:
             - 'auth_key': {'jsonpath_mini': 'auth_token'}

- test:
      - name: "Status"
      - url: "/api/status"
      - method: "POST"
      - body: '{"attributes": {"num_ports": "2", "model": "Phillips", "firmware_ver": "8.0.1", "ipaddress": "192.168.0.0", "rssi": "Not Available"}}'
      - headers: {Content-Type: application/json, auth_token: "$auth_key"}
      - expected_status: [200]
      - group: "Status"
```

Comment: Hey Ravi Teja, Have you got the solution. I also have the same question. If you become able to resolve this, can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

need to use template headers, like

headers: {template: {Content-Type: application/json, auth_token: "$auth_key"}}

Example: 
headers: {template: {'$headername': '$headervalue', '$cache': '$cachevalue'}}

its worked fine now